# Formula for the integral of $(\sin\theta)^{2l+1}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was reading about the orthonormality of the Legendre polynomials when I saw this formula stated without proof:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin\theta)^{2l+1} \; \mathrm d \theta = \frac{2\times 4 \times \cdots \times 2l}{1\times 3 \times 5 \times \cdots \times (2l+1)}
$$
What is this identity called, and how does one go about proving it? Are there any other related/more general formulae?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals

Comment: Or https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function